What is a word or term to describe two things that are directly related in an opposite manner?
I’m looking for a word or term that describes two things that are directly related to eachother in an opposite manner. They go hand-in-hand but are not necessarily opposite in a dictionary, yet can be based on how it’s used in the sentence. A random example is if someone’s level of dishonesty directly affects the level of respect you have for them, where the more dishonest they are, the less you respect them. Is there a word or term that can show the relationship (eg. more = less) between their dishonesty and your respect?

You can use the expression:
inversely proportional
: related by inverse variation.
(MW)

Also inversely correlated.

@FumbleFingers An examination of this term ("inversely correlated") will show that it is essentially found in the literature of science, exact sciences, medical sciences, economic science, etc. "Inversely proportional" is subject to even more stringent criteria: it is limited to mathematics, the mathematics of physics, chemistry, engineering, and so on.

"Inversely proportional" is often used in a metaphorical sense. COCA includes e.g. "Rushman's THEORY OF EMPLOYMENT ASSISTANCE: The availability of help is inversely proportional to your need for it." "her inability to hurt him was inversely proportional to his ability to hurt her" "The emotion generated by an issue is inversely proportional to the quality of the data" "The amount of media interest is inversely proportional to the actual impact on the world." "Inversely correlated" is less common and more restricted to technical writing.

@LPH: I could have included all that myself, but it didn't seem worth it. It doesn't alter the fact that to a first approximation the two expressions are equivalent and interchangeable.

@StuartF In the case of the Rushman example measurable quantities are involved and this is still technical ; I did check more than 400 books (Google) and in the last hundred I found a few cases  of non-technical use. (I found one of those pleasant because of the situatiion  makes for the possibility of real measures—even if they will never be made—, and because of the obvious jocularity: "The amount of hair removed by a barber is inversely proportional to the cost of the haircut.".)
